# mongodb connection using bluebrid problem

Tags: javascript, node.js

mongoClient.connectAsync('mongodb://localhost:27017/prathip/')
^

TypeError: mongoClient.connectAsync is not a function
at Object. (C:\Users\Gnana prahaasam SR\Desktop\Gnana prahaasam SR\Bluebird.js:19:13)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:82:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47

Please help any one to solve this problem

Comment: Do you need to use bluebird?  The [mongo client supports native promises now](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/connection/connect/). If you do need bluebird, include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code  running

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you should add this :

```
mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/your-database
```

Because of the new update you need to add the 0.0.0.0
so you can access your database

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is not a destination address